# Shadow DOM prevents leakage of style but not leakage of script

Tags: html, web-component

I was learning about web components and understood how shadow DOM prevents the leakage of style from the custom component to the main DOM.

But the scripts defined in custom component are still leaking as I am able to access the functions from the main DOM. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Can you show a basic example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript can ***access*** DOM, JavaScript does not run **in** DOM.

Thus shadowDOM has nothing to do with when/how/what JavaScript does.

A Web page has only one **global** scope (running JavaScript)

Thus `<script>` tags you add in shadowDOM run in **global** scope.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just checking if I can limit the scope of the script defined in shadowDOM to just the shadowDOM

Comment: You can't, there is only one global scope, no "shadowDOM scope"

Comment: Got it. Thanks !!